# jQuery isotope centering

Tags: jquery, centering, jquery-isotope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center DIV in DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div)

Please take a look at the image below:

[image]

How can I make the grey squares horizontally centered inside the red container div? This is all made with isotope, so please keep that in mind.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Even if the parent (red) div is always aligned in the middle, the grey, smaller ones are not.
In the top image, when they are aligned in one single column, that column should be in the exact middle of the wrapper (red) div.

Comment: absolutely not. because the current effect is achieved trough javascript (isotope)

Comment: Which calculates the position based on the containing div

Comment: well, it doesn't work anyway, I've also tried by putting a wrapper div between the red one and the smaller grey ones, but still, no luck.

Comment: see my answer for a working example!

Comment: See centering solution in answer below. Basically, it extends Isotope with additional code as recommended on David DeSandro's website.

Comment: Updated my answer with working example, see below.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "DIV within a DIV"

Comment: It's Isotope!!! how is this a duplicate of something that has nothing to do with Isotope's logic ?

Answer (score 21):

It's actually very simple to implement centering for Isotope (just finished a site that does this to look good on mobile touch devices as well as desktop devices). You just include this bit of code from David DeSandro's repository **before** the usual Isotope code at the end of this block

```
<!-- centered layout extension http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ --> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$.Isotope.prototype._getCenteredMasonryColumns = function() {

    this.width = this.element.width();

    var parentWidth = this.element.parent().width();

    var colW = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.columnWidth || // i.e. options.masonry && options.masonry.columnWidth

    this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) || // or use the size of the first item

    parentWidth; // if there's no items, use size of container

    var cols = Math.floor(parentWidth / colW);

    cols = Math.max(cols, 1);

    this.masonry.cols = cols; // i.e. this.masonry.cols = ....
    this.masonry.columnWidth = colW; // i.e. this.masonry.columnWidth = ...
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function() {

    this.masonry = {}; // layout-specific props
    this._getCenteredMasonryColumns(); // FIXME shouldn't have to call this again

    var i = this.masonry.cols;

    this.masonry.colYs = [];
        while (i--) {
        this.masonry.colYs.push(0);
    }
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function() {

    var prevColCount = this.masonry.cols;

    this._getCenteredMasonryColumns(); // get updated colCount
    return (this.masonry.cols !== prevColCount);
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryGetContainerSize = function() {

    var unusedCols = 0,

    i = this.masonry.cols;
        while (--i) { // count unused columns
        if (this.masonry.colYs[i] !== 0) {
            break;
        }
        unusedCols++;
    }

    return {
        height: Math.max.apply(Math, this.masonry.colYs),
        width: (this.masonry.cols - unusedCols) * this.masonry.columnWidth // fit container to columns that have been used;
    };
};
</script>
```

And then you just set up Isotope as usual

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    // the usual stuff for layouting, sorting, filtering, limiting clicks to zones...
</script>
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you container's `margin-right` and `margin-left` are explicitly set to `auto`. Otherwise it wont work, atleast not in chrome.

Comment: I'm struggling to use this with gutters. The gutters aren't working.

Comment: This works, but only when I scale the browser down. Nothing happens when I scale up again. Nobody else with the same issue?

Comment: Having problems putting this together, is the answer outdated? If not, could we get a fiddle example?

Answer (score 13):

Simplest solution found. Use the "masonry" layout inside Isotope:

```
$container.isotope({ 
  itemSelector: '.pbox', 
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  masonry: { 
    isFitWidth: true 
  }
});
```

Comment: the question was for isotope not masonry!

Comment: Works for Isotope too.

Comment: Worth noting that masonry is part of Isotope. Use it inside Isotope this way: `$container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.pbox',
       masonry: {
      isFitWidth: true
    },
    });`